# How can I add a "read more" button to this JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I've created a dynamic product comparison chart. It's basically to which data is written to individual cells if the selection changes in the thead dropdown. I now want to add an array called "tlink" which will dynamically changes the "to website" button.

**The table**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th class="center"><strong>Select Product:</strong></th>
    <th>
        <select class="col2 select">
            <option>Prod1</option>
            <option>Prod2</option>
            <option>Prod3</option>
            <option>Prod4</option>
            <option>Prod5</option>
            <option>Prod6</option>
        </select>
    </th>
    <th>
        <select class="col3 select">
            <option>Prod2</option>
            <option>Prod3</option>
            <option>Prod4</option>
            <option>Prod5</option>
            <option>Prod6</option>
        </select>
    </th>
    <th>
        <select class="col4 select">
            <option>Prod3</option>
            <option>Prod4</option>
            <option>Prod5</option>
            <option>Prod6</option>
        </select>
    </th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Logo</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 logo"><img src="http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo1.jpg"></td>
    <td class="col3 logo"><img src="http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo2.jpg"></td>
    <td class="col4 logo"><img src="http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo3.jpg"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Details 1</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 d1"><img src="http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/green-tick.png"></td>
    <td class="col3 d1"><img src="http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/red-x.png"></td>
    <td class="col4 d1"><img src="http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/green-tick.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><strong>Details 2</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 d2">Some Details</td>
    <td class="col3 d2">Details go here</td>
    <td class="col4 d2">Details or some other things</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Details 3</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 d3">More text about this</td>
    <td class="col3 d3">wow, more text</td>
    <td class="col4 d3">More details go here wow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Details 4</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 d4">Even more details here</td>
    <td class="col3 d4">Even more text and details</td>
    <td class="col4 d4">Almost forgot - more here</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><strong>Rating Icons</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 rating">3 stars</td>
    <td class="col3 rating">1 stars</td>
    <td class="col4 rating">5 stars</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Link to website</strong></td>
    <td class="col2 tlink"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="button-more">Link Button</a></td>
    <td class="col3 tlink"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="button-more">Link Button</a></td>
    <td class="col4 tlink"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="button-more">Link Button</a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**The script**

```
var data = {
"details":
    {
    "info": [
        {
        "name": "Prod1",
        "logo": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo1.jpg",
        "d1": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/green-tick.png",
        "d2": "Some Details",
        "d3": "More textsbout this",
        "d4": "Even more details here",
        "rating": "3 stars",
        "tlink": ""
        },
    {
        "name": "Prod2",
        "logo": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo2.jpg",
        "d1": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/red-x.png",
        "d2": "Details go here",
        "d3": "wow, more text",
        "d4": "Even more text and details",
        "rating": "1 star",
        "tlink": ""
        },
    {
        "name": "Prod3",
        "logo": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo3.jpg",
        "d1": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/green-tick.png",
        "d2": "Details or some other things",
        "d3": "More details go here wow",
        "d4": "Almost forgot - more here",
        "rating": "5 stars",
        "tlink": ""
        },
    {
        "name": "Prod4",
        "logo": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo4.jpg",
        "d1": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/red-x.png",
        "d2": "Some other things",
        "d3": "What should I say",
        "d4": "details go here wow",
        "rating": "4 stars",
        "tlink": ""
        },
     {
        "name": "Prod5",
        "logo": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo5.jpg",
        "d1": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/green-tick.png",
        "d2": "Dunno what to say",
        "d3": "Nice Optics",
        "d4": "State of the art blabla",
        "rating": "4 stars",
        "tlink": ""
        },
     {
        "name": "Prod6",
        "logo": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/demo/arp-compare-demo6.jpg",
        "d1": "http://www.ar-productions.eu/images/icons/red-x.png",
        "d2": "cheap case",
        "d3": "pictures pixeled",
        "d4": "red eyes from flash",
        "rating": "1 star",
        "tlink": ""
        }
    ]}
};

$(".select").change(function() {
var jthis = $(this);
var whichCol;
if (jthis.hasClass("col2")) {
    whichCol = "col2";
} else if
    (jthis.hasClass("col3")) {
    whichCol = "col3";
} else if
(jthis.hasClass("col4")) {
    whichCol = "col4";
}
$.each(data.details.info, function(i, v) {
    if (v.name == jthis.val()) {
        $("td." + whichCol + ".name").html(v.name);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".logo").html("<img src='" + v.logo + "' />");
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d1").html("<img src='" + v.d1 + "' />");
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d2").html(v.d2);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d3").html(v.d3);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".d4").html(v.d4);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".rating").html(v.rating);
        $("td." + whichCol + ".tlink").html(v.tlink);
        return;
    }
});

});
```

You can also see the chart in action on my [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HammerMan/ddXYt/). The string to load is:

```
<a href="#" target="_blank" class="button-more">Link Button</a>
```

as you can see this already contains a class which is part of the theme framework drawing a CSS button. So I need to be able to call the exact string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can copy `<a href='#' target='_blank' class='button-more'>Link Button</a>` in each of product's tlink??

Comment: @Andy: Are you saying if tlink:"http://google.com" then <a href="#" target="http://google.com" class="button-more">Link Button</a>?

Comment: @karthick almost. I need to be able to specify the exact link parameters in the array so that when I add a link to tlink it will have the class button-more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the line

```
$("td." + whichCol + ".tlink").html('<a href="'+v.tlink+'" target="_blank" class="button-more">Link Button</a>');
```

to set the inner HTML of your td cell.
As v.tlink is set as the href attribute, just set http://www.google.com as the tlink in your data.

Comment: Hi @niko, thanks a lot! I will try this first thing in the morning but the line makes total sense to me. thank you!